# How to import datawarehouse to excel without using odbc?

Tags: odbc, databricks, databricks-connect, sql-data-warehouse, excel-import

I want to know how to import data warehouse to excel and load fast without using odbc. It's taking too long to load
platform datawarehouse DATABRICKS

I just tried to import the normal way via odbc, however, it's taking too long and I need to know if there's any other way to import to excel and that's fast